# Targetting multiple frameworks does not work (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

I face an issue with Visual Studio 2022 when I try to target multiple frameworks with the TAG: "multi target" frameworks.

In my `.csproj`, I change the value for

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

and I always get a compilation error.

I try to just add the `net45` in the value, but I still get the error.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net45</TargetFrameworks>
```

If I let the old value (targeting only one framework)

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

everything works fine and I am able to build my project.

When I use `<TargetFrameworks/>`, it looks like the compiler tries to use the .NET framework 4.0 to build and not find some reference that was introduced in the 4.5 framework.

> CS0117 Task do not contain a definition for 'FromResult'

[image]

Any idea what's going on ?